# Is there a verb that means "become extinct"?

Tags: word-request, active-vs-passive

Is there a single verb that means become extinct? 
I have found `disappear` and `vanish`, but I think they don't mean exactly the same as become extinct.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/253505/is-there-a-verb-form-of-extinct (in summary, no, not except some verbs that add further meaning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Die out" and "die off" are commonly used in active-voice sentences, where "become extinct" is used in passive-voice sentences.

If the entire species that goes extinct is often referred to using a singular noun, "die" can be used by itself.  For example, "The buggy whip industry nearly died in the early twentieth century."

Another way to express that an entire category of people or things "became extinct" is to state that the "last" such person or thing "died".  For example, "The last sauropod died 65 million years ago."

The original poster is correct that "disappear" and "vanish" are often used to mean "die out", but (unless the context is very clear) can also mean "become invisible" or "hide" instead.

Answer (score 0):

This answer relates to a single-word verb rather than to a verbal phrase.

---

A *verb* would be highly unusual. As a *verb*, somebody or something has to *do* something *to* somebody or something. There needs to be an agent of some kind.

For instance:

> A meteor [***extinguished***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extinguish) the dinosaurs.

It's assumed from context that this means a meteor was responsible for killing *all* the dinosaurs rather than just a specific group of individuals.

But the meaning isn't explicitly understood without this context. And without context, we would have to add more qualifiers to make it clear it referred to the entire species:

> A meteor *extinguished* all of the dinosaurs that existed.
>   A meteor *extinguished* the race of dinosaurs.

I cannot think of a *verb* that means *to kill every member of a species* without having to resort to some kind of context or qualification.

---

There is the noun [**genocide**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/genocide) and the adjective *genocidal*:

> It committed *genocide* on dinosaurs.
>   It was a *genocidal* act against dinosaurs.

But neither of those are *verbal*. It's not possible to say, for instance:

> It *genocided* dinosaurs.

(Although, in theory, if it *were* used as a verb, the meaning would be understood.)

---

The word [**suicide**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suicide) can be used as a verb. So, although uncommon, it's possible to say:

> She *suicided*.

From Merriam-Webster:

> **suicide** verb
>   **suicided; suiciding**
>
> *intransitive verb*
>   : to commit suicide
>
> *transitive verb*
>   : to put (oneself) to death

But not only would this mean that the species killed *itself*, which would be highly unusual, but we'd have the same problem of having to qualify the noun so as to make it clear that it was *every* member of the race that was referenced rather than just an individual or a few specific members.

---

The verb [**die**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/die) is, of course, possible. But it, too, would require context or qualification so as to make it clear that it was referencing an entire species. (It doesn't carry that connotation as part of its own definition.)

---

In short, there is no *actual* single-word verb I can think of that expresses this concept.

That leaves verbal phrases (such as *killed off* or *died off*), which may also have to be used in context or with some kind of qualification, single-word nouns or adjectives rather than actual verbs, or a coined verbal use of *genocide*.

Comment: Would *exterminated* fit better than *extinguished* ? I'm not sure... You can certainly say the *meteor caused the extinction of the dinosaurs* though

Answer (score 0):

You might consider *defunct* as p[resented in this link](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/defunct#Verb).